# How can I use all the React events with Material-UI components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The Material-UI DataGrid exposes an onCellHover prop, but no event when hovering ends. Is there any way to use standard React events like onMouseLeave?

```
<DataGrid onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} />
```

This does not trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have React react (sorry lol) to `onMouseLeave` just wrap it in another element, like `<div>`, for example.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-fm624?file=/demo.js) is what i've done with the standard MUI codesandbox demo.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.